# In Python without using any package like Numpy or Pandas is there an easy way to slice through a nested list?

Tags: python, list

I have simplified my problem to a much smaller sample dataset when in reality, I am working with a large dataset containing a lap number followed by longitude and latitude in the following format:

```
[[lapNumber0, longitude0, latitude0],[lapNumber0, longitude1, latitude1],[lapNumber1, longitude2, latitude2]...]
```

My goal is to extract the longitudes and latitudes into new lists by lap number. Essentially, I want all of the coordinate pairs corresponding to a given lap in separate lists, but I currently have all the data in one giant nested list. I would try using a library like Pandas or Numpy to tackle the problem, but I am new to Python and need to develop basic slicing and indexing skills before I use any packages.

I decided to break down the problem into a very small and easier example:

```
    sampleList = [[0,1,2],[0,3,4],[1,5,6]]
    newList = []        
    for m in sampleList:
        if sampleList[m][0] == 0:
            n = sampleList[m][1:]
            newList.append(n)
```

For the sample dataset I provided, I am attempting to obtain the result:

`[[1,2],[3,4]]`

Ideally, I wanted to use a dictionary so I could call the lap number and all of the coordinates corresponding to that lap would appear in a list. However, when reading values into the dictionary, the first two values in each lap would not be coordinate pairs but instead were just the longitude and just latitude (i.e., In [1]: lapZero[0] Out [1]: longitude0; In [2]: lapZero[1] Out [2]: latitude0; In [3]: lapZero[2] Out [3]: [longitude1,latitude1] ) and I cannot figure out where the logical error is in my code so I thought slicing into lists would inevitably be easier, especially since the order of the coordinate pairs will matter when I go to map the coordinates using arcpy.

I sincerely appreciate everybody's time and feedback to help answer my question!

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you really want is a bit different from how the question is phrased. This answer is to create a dictionary such that in your example we would get

```py
desired_dictionary[0] = [[1,2], [3,4]]
```

I write it in a very simple way so that it is clear to newcomers to Python:

```py
desired_dictionary = {}
for lap_number, longitude, latitude in sampleList:
    if lap_number not in desired_dictionary:
        desired_dictionary[lap_number] = []
    desired_dictionary[lap_number].append([longitude, latitude])
```

This way we also get multiple entries with the same longitude and latitude if that appears in the data. If you would rather not have repetitions, we can use set of tuples instead of list of lists, as follows:

```py
desired_dictionary = {}
for lap_number, longitude, latitude in sampleList:
    if lap_number not in desired_dictionary:
        desired_dictionary[lap_number] = set()
    desired_dictionary[lap_number].add( (longitude, latitude) )
```